# QML image shows black rectangular for images with pixels>2000

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have faced a problem while working with qml image, It only shows images with pixels<2000 and for other images it shows a black rectangular,
this is another topic about this subject.
https://forum.qt.io/topic/45355/qml-image-showing-black-rectangle-instead-of-image.

well. how I can show images bigger than 2000 pixels? what about using `QQuickImageProvider`?

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Image {
        id: image1
        x: 10
        y: 10
        source: "testImage.png"
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try to implement it using `QQuickImageProvider`? Or you can create your own item, I guess just by copying Qt [sources](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.10/src/quick/items/qquickimage.cpp) to check it in debugger.

Comment: @folibis no I have not checked. It was just an idea, so you mean qquickimage itself uses Imageprovider?So it does not work, hum?